# Analytical evaluation of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-forms, exponential-sum, summation-method

I am trying to calculate the infinite series
$$\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1} e^{-(n-1)^2\pi}}{1-e^{  (2 n-1)\pi}}\simeq -0.0903244354808$$
Are there any any analytical methods to compute such series exactly?

Context: Such series appear as values of certain modular forms.

Comment: As first step you should prove that your series is absolutely converging.
To do so split your series as: $S = a_0 + \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_i + \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} b_i$, then you have to show that both series are absolutely converging and that $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_i + \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} b_i = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (a_i + b_i)$ for absolutely converging series.

Comment: I see, but how does it help me to evaluate it?

Comment: If your series is converging but not absolutely converging, then you can rearrange it so that it converges to any real number. This is known as the Riemann Series Theorem. So your question is only well-defined if your series is absolutely converging.

Comment: It seems like it would be very difficult to get an exact value, if it is even possible.

The value seems very close to $$-\frac{1.99984556321}{e^\pi-1}.$$ WA gives the same result up to the decimal values given.

Comment: Numerically, I have $-0.09$ not $+$.

Comment: @user777777777 How is this representation meaningful? Are you thinking since it's close to $-2/(e^\pi-1)$?

Comment: @GEdgar You're right, I changed it in the question.

Comment: @ElRafu Yeah exactly, it hints at a possible closed form, which I honestly think doesn't exist in terms of elementary functions. If you evaluate the series at $n=0,$ you get $-\frac1{e^\pi-1}.$

Comment: @ElRafu You say that these numbers appear as values of certain modular forms. Can you give us the modular form in question (as q-expansion, with level and weight)? If you evaluate the modular form at a quadratic imaginary then I seem to remember that it will always be expressible as a product of an algebraic number, a power of pi and a gamma-function evaluated at a rational, but it if you provide the modular form we can check it in your case (if it is evaluated at a quadratic imaginary).

Comment: @Testcase Right, are you referring to complex multiplication points? The series is essentially the value $F(i)$ for the holomorphic function $$F(\tau)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{(-1)^nq^{\frac{n^2}{2}}}{1-q^{n-\frac12}}$$ with $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$. It is a mock modular form rather than a modular form and the $q$-series is the OEIS sequence A256209.

Comment: @Testcase I'm very interested in general statements of these types, would you know any reference with a precise statement?

Comment: From OEIS page I see that Michael Somos has done research on this series. Let's hope they see this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer since it might be a bit too long for a comment.

Given a quadratic imaginary field $K$ there exists a number $\Omega_K \in \mathbb{C^{\times}}$ such that for any (classical) modular form $f$ of weight $k$, and any $\tau \in K$ with positive imaginary part (i.e. your CM points) we have that
$$ f(\tau) \in \bar{\mathbb{Q}} \cdot\Omega_k^{2k}.$$
This is discussed at length in Don Zagiers excellent notes 'Elliptic modular forms and their applications' where the statement above occurs as Proposition 26.

Determining the number $\Omega_K$ given above for the full modular group can be done using the so-called Chowla-Selberg formula (also discussed in the notes by Don Zagier, allthough a complete proof is only sketched). For instance the Chowla-Selberg formula gives
$$E_4(i) = \frac{3\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^8}{(2\pi)^6}.$$

In your case we are looking at a mock modular form, hence the statement above does not apply directly. That being said, a bit of googling using the frase 'Chowla Selberg mock modular' leads me to the article 'Hecke structures of weakly holomorphic modular forms and their algebraic properties' by
Dohoon Choia and Subong Limb (Journal of number theory, volume 184, p. 428-450). I am not sure it directly relates to your question, but it does seem to derive a certain Chowla-Selberg formula for mock modular forms.

To tie this to your specific series, note that in the context of mock modular forms it appears to be a special case of an Appell-Lerch sum, and these were studied extensively by Sanders Zwegers.

Comment: Thank you, that's brilliant! I was not familiar with the Chowla-Selberg formula, and it seem precisely like what I was looking for. I will look in more detail into the paper you suggested. For now it seems that an analogue of the Chowla-Selberg formula applies for sure for the completions of mock modular forms (since in contrast to mock modular form they transform modularly).